# Lock() is not locking a dictionary entry

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have callbacks competing for access to a static dictionary that needs to be thread safe. Two different entries can be accessed at the same time, but same entry can't be accessed multiple times.
To do this I use lock statement on the entry I wish to access ( lock(dictionary[key]) ).
Here is  the callback function:

```
    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Guid guid = (Guid)ar.AsyncState;
        lock (RoutingTable.connParams[guid])
        {
            WMFormThread.wmForm.WriteLine(guid.ToString() + " in " + RoutingTable.connParams[guid].sendingBuffer.Count());
            try
            {
                int bytesSent = RoutingTable.connParams[guid].socket.EndSend(ar);
                RoutingTable.connParams[guid].UpdateAck(bytesSent);
                RoutingTable.connParams[guid].bytesToSend -= (uint)bytesSent;
                RoutingTable.connParams[guid].bytesSent += bytesSent;
                if (RoutingTable.connParams[guid].bytesSent == RoutingTable.connParams[guid].sendingBuffer[0].Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.PayloadLength)
                {
                    RoutingTable.connParams[guid].bytesSent = 0;
                    RoutingTable.connParams[guid].sendingBuffer.RemoveAt(0);
                    if (RoutingTable.connParams[guid].sendingBuffer.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (RoutingTable.connParams[guid].sendingBuffer[0].Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.PayloadLength > 0)
                            RoutingTable.connParams[guid].socket.BeginSend(RoutingTable.connParams[guid].sendingBuffer[0].Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Payload.ToArray(), 0, RoutingTable.connParams[guid].sendingBuffer[0].Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.PayloadLength, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), guid);
                        if ((RoutingTable.connParams[guid].sendingBuffer[0].Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.ControlBits & TcpControlBits.Fin) > 0)
                            RoutingTable.connParams[guid].socket.BeginDisconnect(false, new AsyncCallback(DisconnectCallback), guid);
                    }
                    Main.tapWorker.SendAck(guid);
                }
                else
                {
                    WMFormThread.wmForm.WriteLine("frag");
                    RoutingTable.connParams[guid].socket.BeginSend(RoutingTable.connParams[guid].sendingBuffer[0].Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.Payload.ToArray(), RoutingTable.connParams[guid].bytesSent, RoutingTable.connParams[guid].sendingBuffer[0].Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.PayloadLength - RoutingTable.connParams[guid].bytesSent, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), guid);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e is SocketException || e is ObjectDisposedException)
                {
                    RoutingTable.RequestAccess();
                    if (!RoutingTable.connStatus[guid].remoteEPFin)
                        Main.tapWorker.SendRst(guid);
                    RoutingTable.connStatus[guid].remoteEPFin = true;
                    RoutingTable.connStatus[guid].localEPFin = true;
                    RoutingTable.ReleaseAccess();
                    WMFormThread.wmForm.WriteLine(guid.ToString() + " oute " + RoutingTable.connParams[guid].sendingBuffer.Count);
                    return;
                }
                WMFormThread.wmForm.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            WMFormThread.wmForm.WriteLine(guid.ToString() + " out " + RoutingTable.connParams[guid].sendingBuffer.Count);
        }
    }
```

And for most of the time it works as expected, but occasionally, I can see this:

```
aabe54ee-8d4e-4fb8-9559-cf257f3621d1 in <-- first lock
aabe54ee-8d4e-4fb8-9559-cf257f3621d1 in <-- second lock while the first one is still on
aabe54ee-8d4e-4fb8-9559-cf257f3621d1 out<-- second lock is done
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: <-- first lock resumes and crashes because the second lock didn't wait for the first lock to exit and cleared a buffer
```

When packets queue up BeginSend method is called inside the callback. For most of the time it locks fine, but occasionally this is what happens:

- first "if" checks if the whole packet was sent
- if it was, the packet is removed from the list
- the second "if" checks to see if there are more packets to send
- if there are, and it holds TCP data (is not a control packet) BeginSend is called
- after BeginSend is done, a new callback is called, but it should wait for the first one to finish
- unfortunately, sometimes, it doesn't and it clears the packet from sendingBuffer list
- when the first callback resumes, it continues with the last "if" and checks if the FIN flag is set, but because the second call removed it crashes with a ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Any thoughts on why could the second lock not wait for the first one to exit?

**edit:** This is what each dictionary entry holds. An instance of this class:

```
    public class ConnParams
    {
        public IList<Packet> sendingBuffer = new List<Packet>();
        public byte[] receivingBuffer = new byte[Main.tapWorker.MSS];
        public Socket socket;
        public ushort localPort;
        public IpV4Address remoteIp;
        public ushort remotePort;
        public uint ack;
        public uint seq;
        public byte windowScale;
        public ushort windowSize;
        public int freeWindow;
        public bool windowFull = false;
        public uint bytesToSend = 0;
        public int bytesSent = 0;
        public int bytesReceived = 0;
        public ConnParams()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            this.seq = (uint)(random.Next(0xffff)) << 16 | (uint)(random.Next(0xffff));
        }
        public void UpdateSeq(uint seqInc)
        {
            this.seq = (uint)(((UInt64)this.seq + (UInt64)seqInc) % 0x100000000);
        }
        public void UpdateSeq(int seqInc)
        {
            this.seq = (uint)(((UInt64)this.seq + (UInt64)seqInc) % 0x100000000);
        }
        public void UpdateAck(uint ackInc)
        {
            this.ack = (uint)(((UInt64)this.ack + (UInt64)ackInc) % 0x100000000);
        }
        public void UpdateAck(int ackInc)
        {
            this.ack = (uint)(((UInt64)this.ack + (UInt64)ackInc) % 0x100000000);
        }
        public ushort GetWindow()
        {
            return (ushort)(0xfaf0 << this.windowScale > this.bytesToSend ? (0xfaf0 << this.windowScale) - this.bytesToSend : 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @rene: There's no indication that the lock is obtained on a GUID - it's obtained on `RoutingTable.connParams[guid]`

Comment: I'm not locking on guid, I'm locking on connParams[guid] which is a dictionary entry with the value an object

Comment: Does anything modify the contents of `RoutingTable.connParams`? If so, that could certainly explain the issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet that is why I'm locking, because I'm modifying parameters in each callback

Comment: What do you mean by "modifying parameters"? If you're changing the value of `connParams[guid]` then by the time the second thread comes in, the dictionary could have a different value so you'd obtain a different lock... hence the problem. It sounds like you might want a separate dictionary which *doesn't* change, just for the lock associated with each guid.

Comment: @JonSkeet so if I do this inside the lock I loose the lock? "RoutingTable.connParams[guid].bytesToSend -= (uint)bytesSent;"

Comment: No, that's not changing the value of `connParams[guid]`. That's just changing data within the object that the value refers to. It doesn't help that we don't even know the type of `connParams`... you really should provide more context.

Comment: A lock can be obtained more than once on the same object on the same thread. Are you sure that's not what you're seeing? Let me explain why I'm asking. I'm pretty sure that there's no bug in the lock statement or the code that it generates. "pretty sure" means that I'm inclined towards either a bug in your code or something that ends up not being the way you assumed it would be. Either way, Jon is right, you need to provide more context.

Comment: Why can multiple locks be obtained on the same object? Isn't that the whole purpose of the lock statement? (How can I open chat. The option disappeared?)

Comment: As [per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), the lock statement ensures that only one *thread* can enter a section protected by the lock object. It does not protect the same thread from entering such a section twice. As for chat, it might come back if enough comments are added, or there's always the [C# chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lasse V. Karlsen, we discovered that the problem was multiple callbacks running on the same thread.
From my observations, asynchronous sockets use a separated thread for each callback, but unfortunately, occasionally, it reuses the thread for another callback, and the lock() statement ensures locking only between different threads. If the same thread tries to lock on the same object it will succeed.

Bellow is the log just before a crash. Each line represents the following:

[guid] [in(locked)\out(unlocked)] [nr of packets in queue] [thread ID]

[image]

Just before the exception you can see a lock on the dictionary entry with the guid 199699d9-9f19-44c7-9b69-da3290252257, with thread ID 16. Because there is another packet in the buffer it calls again BeginSend, which in turn calls a new callback, that for some reason is put on the same thread 16 before the first callback had a chance to exit. Because it's running on the same thread, it's going to get a lock on the same dictionary entry and cause mayhem.